# Why can't change my desktop background?

Tags: 12.10

When I right click> change desktop backgroud, and it takes me to the system settings screen.
there's no "appearance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that this package has not been removed accidentally:

**gnome-control-center-unity**

If so, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity
```